# Why do I Get Different Results Using Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, math

I've made a simple program that counts matrices, here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int result[3] = {0,0,0};
int matrixc[3][6] = {
        {0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {0,0,0,1,1,1},
        {1,0,1,0,0,1}
        };
for(int x=0;x <3;x++)
{
    for(int y=0;y < 6;y++)
    {           
        result[x] += (matrixc[x][y] * pow(2,6-y));
    }
    cout << result[x] << endl;
}
}
```

The output is what I wanted, it is: `2,14,and 82`.
But, when I delete the initialization in the integer array of `result`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int result[3]; //deleted initialization
int matrixc[3][6] = {
        {0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {0,0,0,1,1,1},
        {1,0,1,0,0,1}
        };
for(int x=0;x <3;x++)
{
    for(int y=0;y < 6;y++)
    {           
        result[x] += (matrixc[x][y] * pow(2,6-y));
    }
    cout << result[x] << endl;
}
}
```

I got odd outputs: `1335484418,32618, and 65617`.

Would you like to explain me why would the output be different between an array with and without an initialization?

Actually, I don't want to initialize all `result` array, because I have a huge data of matrices.

Is it possible if I use `std::vector` without initializing all of the `result` array?

Comment: `int result[3]` leaves `result` with undetermined values and then you do a `+` on each entry so you are adding to an unknown value.

Comment: Always initialize things before you do math with them...

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. It should have told you what your mistake was.

Comment: You said you don't want to initialize *all* `result` array. What does that mean, exactly? In your code above you are using *all* `result` array, which means that you will have to initialize it in its entirety, whether you want it or not. What about yourt actual code? Are you always using the entire `result` array there?

Comment: If the initialization values are all zeros, you can initialize the array with: `int results[3] = {0};`.

Comment: @ Ferruccio: In C++ you can make it even shorter `int results[3] = {};`.

Comment: @anarchy99: Basically, you need to explain what your question is about. Every answer so far seems to be about "garbage in uninitialized valriables". This is true, yet it seems that your question in essense is about the performance penalty imposed by initailization of the huge result array. If so, you need probide more details about it. "Dumb" total initialization can be avoided in many circumstances.

Answer (score 6):

> Would you like to explain me why would the output be different between an array with and without an initialization?

Without initialisation, automatic variables aren't initialised. They will have an indeterminate value, depending on what happened to be in the memory they occupy.

> Actually, I don't want to initialize all "result" array, because I have a huge data of matrices.

You can zero-initialise the whole array, even if it's huge, like this:

```
int result[huge] = {};
```

although, if it is huge, then it shouldn't be an automatic variable. These are typically kept on the stack, which is typically not huge and liable to overflow if you put too much stuff on it.

> Is it possible if I use std::vector without initializing all of the "result" array?

Yes, a vector will zero-initialise its elements by default.

Answer (score 1):

Without the initialization, the `result` array contains undetermined values, i.e. values that could be anything that fits into an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete the initialization of the `result` array, those locations are initially set to unspecified, arbitrary values. You then add to this arbitrary value within the `for` loop, and end up those unexpected results. The results may be completely different the next time you run your program.

Also, since `result[x] += ...` reads from an uninitialized variable, deleting the initialization results in your code having undefined behavior.

If you switch over to using a `vector` you can zero initialize it as

```
std::vector<int> result(count);  // zero initialized with `count` elements
```

or

```
std::vector<int> result; // contains zero elements
result.resize(count);    // now it contains `count` elements, all set to 0
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment if you do not initialize `result` it will have undetermined values. Later on your are then adding a value to an unknown value which will still be an unknown value. In this situation you need to initialize your data, can `zero` initialize like so:

```
int result[3] = {} ;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Would you like to explain me why would the output be different between an array with and without an initialization?

Seriously?  If you don't initialize the array elements  they are not initialized!

That means they contains junk data, so when you do `result[x] += xxx;` you are adding to junk, so you get more junk.

> Actually, I don't want to initialize all "result" array, because I have a huge data of matrices.

Then you shouldn't rely on their initial value being zero.

You can do this:

```
int result[3] = { };  // initialize all elements to zero
```

> Is it possible if I use std::vector without initializing all of the "result" array?

`std::vector` always initializes its members.